# Custom Column Searching & Filtering in Material Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I have a column in my table called Active.  Data in this column is returned as `1 or 0` for Active and Inactive.

These values are not displayed as 1 or 0.  Instead, using the `render` prop, I have a function `generateFlagText` which looks for the value and renders an MUI Chip component.

Users cannot search the column by typing Active or Inactive, they would have to type 1 or 0, but they don't know this.

How can I write a check for Active or Inactive to display only those rows in the table using the `customSearchAndFilter` prop in Material-Table?

This is my column and function:

```
{
    title: <Typography className={classes.colHeader}>Active</Typography>,
    field: "Active",
    render: (rowData) => generateFlagText(rowData.Active),
    // customFilterAndSearch: (term, rowData) => console.log(term), // term is the user input   
},
...

export function generateFlagText(status) {
    if (status === 1) 
        return (
            <Chip
                label={"Active"}
                style={{
                    backgroundColor: "#D9F5FD",
                    border: "1px solid #5CC1EE",
                    borderRadius: "4px",
                    color: "#0063B8",
                }}
            />
        );
    if (status === 0)
        return (
            <Chip
                label={"Inactive"}
                style={{
                    backgroundColor: "#FFEBF5",
                    border: "1px solid #F69AC6",
                    borderRadius: "4px",
                    color: "#A8396F",
                }}
            />
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make something like this

```
const data = { type: "active" };
const rows = [
  { name: 1, active: 1 },
  { name: 2, active: 0 }
];

function f(data, rows) {
  const mappedValues = {
    active: 1,
    inactive: 0
  };

  const currFilter = [];
  Object.keys(mappedValues).forEach((key) => {
    if (key.includes(data.type)) {
      currFilter.push(mappedValues[key]);
    }
  });

  return rows.filter((row) =>
    currFilter.some((filterValue) => filterValue === row.active)
  );
}

console.log(f(data, rows));
```

User can input any text and function return rows which includes symbols from ui table.
But it would be easier to make not an input, but a selection of two values in a selector